# Calling a function at setInterval Jscript

Tags: timer, setinterval, jscript

i have a image slider, and i am wanting to call the fader function at the end of the timer, unfortunately, im a complete novice and only seem to be NOT LEARNING from my mistakes... I know im floating in a boat full of the same kind ,So please could a good sailor divert this boat in the right direction for us. We would all be most great-full of your service..

I have code here, If anybody can explain where im going wrong i would be very happy. Thank you

```
<script>
function fader (){
var element = document.getElementById("dynamic-image");
element.style.transitionDuration = "2s";
<!---the grabbed element + style [ execute type of effect ] = ' dimension of effect (1 ,2)';--->
 element.style.opacity=0;
}
</script>

<script>

(function() {
   'use strict';

   var preloads=[],c,
       d=document,di=d.getElementById('dynamic-image'),
       dh=d.getElementById('dynamic-href'),
       url=[
           'linkmywebsite.ml','chatmagbingo.com','ilkestonwebdesign.com','ipost.com','happypetsuk.com','www.linkmywebsite.co.uk'
          ];


function preload(){
for(c=0;c<arguments.length;c++) {
   preloads[preloads.length]=new Image();
   preloads[preloads.length-1].src=arguments[c];
  }
   c=0;
 }


preload('yournewsite2.png','1ad.jpg','2ad.jpg',
'3ad.jpg','4ad.jpg','5ad.jpg');



setInterval(

function starttimer() {

   dh.href='http://'+url[c];
   di.src=preloads[c].src;
   di.alt=preloads[c].src.substring(preloads[c].src.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
   c++;
if(c==preloads.length) {
   c=0;
  }

 },5000);

}());
```

Not sure where to call the function Fader. thank you....

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer..... again i figure it out...lol

So heres a image fader for that boatfull of novices...simplified.....

```
<style type="text/css">

.dynamic-image {
position:absolute;
 left:0%;
 top:0%; 
 width:100%; 
 height:100%;


</style>




<img id="dynamic-image" class="dynamic-image" src="ebayad.png";>


<script>
function fader (){
var element = document.getElementById("dynamic-image");
element.style.transitionDuration = "2s";
<!---the grabbed element + style [ execute type of effect ] = ' dimension of effect (1 ,2)';--->
 element.style.opacity=4;
}
</script>

<script>
function fader2 (){
var element = document.getElementById("dynamic-image");
element.style.transitionDuration = "2s";
<!---the grabbed element + style [ execute type of effect ] = ' dimension of effect (1 ,2)';--->
 element.style.opacity=0;
}

</script>

<script>


setInterval( fader2, 4000 );



(function() {
   'use strict';

   var preloads=[],c,
      di=document.getElementById('dynamic-image');


function preload(){
for(c=0;c<arguments.length;c++) {
   preloads[preloads.length]=new Image();
   preloads[preloads.length-1].src=arguments[c];
  }
   c=0;
 }


preload('yournewsite2.png','1ad.jpg','2ad.jpg',
'3ad.jpg','4ad.jpg','5ad.jpg');

setInterval( fader, 8000 );



setInterval(

function starttimer() {


   di.src=preloads[c].src;

   c++;
if(c==preloads.length) {
   c=0;
  }

 },8000);

}());



</script>
```